How would super high voltage and high amperage affect the number of windings in an electromagnet?
If you use a high resistivity material (either being due to small cross section of wires or poor conductivity of material), you could increase the voltage to kilovolts proportionally to the resistance, which would allow for lower losses.
That would also allow for you to pass higher amperage currents without overheating the wire.
The rule of thumb is that the lower the cross-section of a wire and its amperage, the more turns you need to make in an electromagnet to have the same power as an electromagnet with higher gauge and amperage.
But since you are using incredibly high voltage to pass a lot of amperage, I'm not so sure how that would affect the number of windings in an electromagnet.

You've got a major misconception here; what you describe would do nothing but increase losses.

Resistivity is an inherent property of a material, changing the thickness or shape of a conductor doesn't change that. It's resistance changes based on cross sectional area and length.

Quite the opposite in fact. The magnetic field strength of a solenoid, B, is proportional to the number of turns, N, and the current through them, I; B = kNI where k is a proportionality constant having to do with relative permeabilities and the length of the solenoid. Increasing the resistivity of the wires means that you will need a higher voltage to get the same I through them, as you say, but this has no effect on the strength of the field, it merely increases the losses (I²R). You may be conflating this with the concept of high voltage power transmission where extreme voltages can reduce losses while keeping transmitted power constant.
It also increases the spacing of the windings since the turn-to-turn voltage difference is now higher and the insulation must increase in thickness to compensate. This lowers the proportionality factor of the B field, making the strength even lower.

The limiting factor in most electromagnets is temperature. You can increase the current supplied to them, which increases the field, until the windings get so hot that the insulation is in danger of damage.
Consider that the magnet is wound in two identical sections. We can put them in series, or in parallel. The power and field in either case is the same. However in series, the voltage and number of turns are double the parallel case. In parallel, the current and cross-sectional area are double the series case. If you wind in N sections, or iterate the process, you can design a magnet to more or less any number of turns you like.
This illustrates that the only really free parameter in a magnet of any given size is how much power you put into it. The voltage to current ratio can be varied by varying the cross section of the wire and the number of turns. For calculation purposes, you can even consider a single turn, though we never actually use something as extreme as the lead-out wires would now be a practical problem. Similarly having a billion turns is a practical problem of the availability of fine wire, rather than a fundamental problem.
